# String interpolation TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the Python string interpolation with `%s` for my parameter variable. My variable is `name` and the value in this variable I would like to insert it where I have put `%s`. My code snippet is:

```
def select_dataset(self, name):
    # Params name: The name of the dataset e.g. CRM
    name_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="data_configuration_datasets_ct_fields_body"]/tbody/tr/td/div/span[@title="%s" and contains(text(), "%s")]/preceding::input[1]' % name % name).click()
```

The error is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore Regression Test\ClearCore - Regression Test\TestCases\DatasetsPage_TestCase.py", line 146, in test_a2_edit_datasets
    ds.select_dataset("Edit_test")
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore Regression Test\ClearCore - Regression Test\Pages\datasets.py", line 281, in select_dataset
    name_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="data_configuration_datasets_ct_fields_body"]/tbody/tr/td/div/span[@title="%s" and contains(text(), "%s") % name]/preceding::input[1]' % name).click()
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

The line where the `%s` and `%name` is here:

```
name_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="data_configuration_datasets_ct_fields_body"]/tbody/tr/td/div/span[@title="%s" and contains(text(), "%s")]/preceding::input[1]' % name % name).click()
```

The Test Case which calls the method:

```
def test_a2_edit_datasets(self):
    print "*** Test edit_dataset ***"
    menu_bar = MenuBarPage(self.driver)
    tool_bar = ToolbarPage(self.driver)
    project_navigator = ProjectNavigatorPage(self.driver)
    ds = project_navigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Datasets")
    ds.click_add_datasets()
    time.sleep(1)
    ds.add_datasets_name_description_and_datamap("Edit_test", Globals.dataset_description) # adds the name, description and selects datamap drop down for the Dataset
    ds.add_name_type_and_size_for_key_fields(Globals.dataset_crm_name_keyField, Globals.dataset_type_string)
    ds.click_save_datasets()
    #ds.select_dataset(Globals.dataset_name_crm)
    ds.select_dataset("Edit_test")
```

Where should I put the `%`?

Comment: It's not where the `%s` is, it's how you're passing the arguments - try `% (name, name)` at the end instead of `% name % name`.

Comment: You put it as an answer then I can tick it

Comment: It's just a typo - the docs show you how to do this, please read them next time.